# How to call stored procedure in Linq to SQL, I am getting data from Form collection returns -1 when call db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, stored-procedures

Any one here who could help me!!

How to call stored procedure in Linq to SQL, I am getting data from Form collection, And then i want to call stored procedure which return multiple rows and then I want to pass it to view (And plz tell me how to display data in without model by using affected rows object)
I call stored procedure in this way but it gives me in rows = -1

```
          [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ReportTVPSA(FormCollection collection)
        {
            int fiscal_year = int.Parse(collection["FinancialYearIDFrom"]);
            int prev_year = fiscal_year - 1;
            int month_frm = int.Parse(collection["MonthFrom"]);
            var month_to = collection["MonthTo"];
            string division = collection["dvn_code"];
            var rand = DBNull.Value;
            DateTime FDate, TDate;
            DateTime.TryParse(collection["dateFrom"], out FDate);
            var dateFrom = FDate;

            DateTime.TryParse(collection["dateTo"], out TDate);
            var date_to = TDate;

            string ReportBaseTypeDoOrInvoice = collection["ReportBaseTypeDoOrInvoice"];
            string ReportBaseTypeQuantityOrRevenue = collection["ReportBaseTypeQuantityOrRevenue"];

            int SegmentLevel = int.Parse(collection["SegmentLevel"]);
            string segment_codes = collection["segment_codes"];
            string sg_cd_frm = collection["sg_cd_frm"];
            string sg_cd_to = collection["sg_cd_to"];

            string location = collection["show_customers"];
            string cst_CodeFrom = collection["cst_CodeFrom"];
            string cst_CodeTo = collection["cst_CodeTo"];

            var rows = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("sp_GetTargetVSPrimarySalesAnalysisForZones @FinancialYear, @PreviousFinancialYear, @Month, @dvn_code, @DateFrom, @DateTo, @ReportBaseTypeDoOrInvoice, @ReportBaseTypeQuantityOrRevenue, @SegmentLevel, @SegmentCode, @SegmentCodeFrom, @SegmentCodeTo, @cst_Code, @cst_CodeFrom, @cst_CodeTo",
                new SqlParameter("@FinancialYear", fiscal_year),
                new SqlParameter("@PreviousFinancialYear", prev_year),
                new SqlParameter("@Month", month_to),
                new SqlParameter("@dvn_code", division),
                new SqlParameter("@DateFrom", dateFrom),
                new SqlParameter("@DateTo", date_to),
                new SqlParameter("@ReportBaseTypeDoOrInvoice", ReportBaseTypeDoOrInvoice),
                new SqlParameter("@ReportBaseTypeQuantityOrRevenue", ReportBaseTypeQuantityOrRevenue),
                new SqlParameter("@SegmentLevel", SegmentLevel),
                new SqlParameter("@SegmentCode", rand),
                new SqlParameter("@SegmentCodeFrom", sg_cd_frm),
                new SqlParameter("@SegmentCodeTo", sg_cd_to),
                new SqlParameter("@cst_Code", rand),
                new SqlParameter("@cst_CodeFrom", cst_CodeFrom),
                new SqlParameter("@cst_CodeTo", cst_CodeTo));

            return View();
        }
```

Comment: SQL returns 10 minus the severity level of the error, if you're getting -1 then you have a severity 11 which is SqlErrorCollection

Comment: @LiviuBoboia Can you plz tell me how to resolve it??

Comment: Run the command on your sql server and see exactly where the problem is

Comment: Any one here who resolve my issues? plz